# How to access properties of a view controller loaded from storyboard?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, storyboard

I have a view controller instance created with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` like this:

```
TBSCTestController* testController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"OTP"];
```

`TBSCTestController` has an `IBOutlet` property named `label` which is hooked up with a label in the storyboard:

[image: IBOutlet albel]

I want to modify the text of `label` using this code but nothing changes:

```
testController.label.text = @"newText";
[self.view addSubview: testController.view];
```

The `testController` is a valid instance but the `label` is nil.
What did i miss?

Comment: I would guess that your label is not hooked up to your IBOutlet since you are doing this the right way.

Comment: @lnafziger I've checked my storyboard and the label is already hooked up with my IBOutlet.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but what if you switch those last two lines?

Comment: @lnafziger It should matter, see my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `UILabel` is `nil` because you have instantiated your controller but it didn't load its view. The view hierarchy of the controller is loaded the first time you ask for access to its view. So, as @lnafziger suggested (though it **should** matter for this exact reason) if you switch the two lines it will work. So:

```
[self.view addSubview: testController.view];  
testController.label.text = @"newText";
```

As an example to illustrate this point, even this one would work:

```
// Just an example. There is no need to do it like this...
UIView *aView = testController.view;
testController.label.text = @"newText";
[self.view addSubview: testController.view];
```

Or this one:

```
[testController loadView];
testController.label.text = @"newText";
[self.view addSubview: testController.view];
```

Comment: BEWARE! Apple advices against calling this method directly. When you call this method directly, you will not get your ViewDidLoad method called and you will see some potentially erratic behavior.

Comment: @MarkL And that's why I have a note saying _There is no need to do it like this..._ That was just an example to help the OP understand the problem.

Comment: @Alladinian, it's not obvious to me that you were advising against this approach. I just wanted others to know that the loadView approach is not recommended by Apple, and will eliminate the ViewDidLoad call from occurring.

Comment: @MarkL can you recommend a better approach?